# Magento - Solr - broken index

Tags: magento, solr

We have a problem with the Magento Solr search engine. We refresh the search indices once every night. The search index update setting is 'Manual update'. Nightly update is done by cron.

Sometimes some products are not findable by search, mostly for just 1 store view (we have 4 store-views). This is (obviously) problematic for us, as it are often popular products. The search results (for example from the search query table in magento) show clearly something went wrong for the store view: for the same query all the other store views have the same amount of results, the problematic store-view has 0 results.

Not no products are indexed, a lot of products are still found, it just seems some subset was not indexed.

The odd thing is, when we do a new reindex (of the catalogsearch_fulltext index) it works perfectly again.

As far as we know, no different settings where applied for any of the stores/store-views. We have near to no knowledge of the Solr engine.

Help/ideas appreciated.

Comment: We're having similar issues on two of our sites with SOLR - did you get anywhere with this? A temporary fix we tried and so far has worked is to make sure you're using 'Final Commit', stop SOLR from running, create a new data/ folder (where indexes are stored), rename the old data folder, start SOLR again, reindex the catalogsearch_fulltext index, and then change to 'Partial Commit' so that results are not lost if indexes crash. Some results may be dated, but at least you have indexes with integrity and products can be found.

Comment: I think it was solved after we received a patch from Magento. I'm not sure which version you are using? We were using 10.0.0.2.

Comment: Lucasmus, you received a patch from Magento? Do you mean a version upgrade or an actual patch? Where did you find it? Thanks.

Comment: We have recently updated our version of SOLR and had some luck with that. We are also trying to install Tomcat on a different server and running it. Are there any other indexes running at the same time?

Comment: What helped a lot for me where incorrectly configured values for products. It seems SOLR generated a lot of error output for them in var/log/exception.log. When I fixed those, a lot of missing products showed up.